# Depth buffer not working for alpha render pass in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have a scene with transparent and opaque 2d items. I first render the opaque items with depth test and depth mask (writing) enabled, in front to back order. Then I set the depth mask to false (without disabling the depth test), enable blending and render the transparent ones from back to front.

But the problem is that the transparent items are not drawn properly. When I use glDepthFunc(GL_LESS) for them they are not drawn at all and when I use glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL) they are drawn but the ones that should be obscured by opaque items are not. They just render on top of everything really.

The code in the render routine looks like this:

```
// Set the clear color
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glClearDepthf(1.f);
glDepthRangef(0.f, 1.f);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// Draw opaque items

glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);   

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

renderOpaque();


// Draw transparent items

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

renderAlpha();

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

The z values for the items are set in the following manner:

```
// Bottom layer (background) is 0 and then layer is incremented
// by one for each view that sits on top
// I use the far value (something like 10000.f) to divide to get
// something between 0.0 and 1.0 (from back to front: 0.0/10k, 1.0/10k,
// 2.0/10k etc)

float zTranslation = static_cast<float>(GetLayer()) /
TheCamera::Instance().GetFar();
glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f),
        glm::vec3(m_absoluteFrame.origin.x,
        m_absoluteFrame.origin.y,
        zTranslation));
glm::mat4 MVP = muiKit::TheCamera::Instance().GetProjection() * 
        muiKit::TheCamera::Instance().GetView() * 
        model;
```

The MVP matrix is then passed to the shader to set gl_Position...

```
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(imageVertex.xyz, 1);
```

And I also pass texture coordinates and indexes and so on and draw using glDrawElements in batches.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, even though I'm new to this I get the feeling that the depth function should be GL_GREATER when I render transparent items... no? Somehow it makes sense to me knowing that I'm rendering them in back to front order.

Comment: Dumb question, probably: are you sure your target has a depth buffer attached?

Comment: Hmmm... not dump at all. I was thinking about this. Do I need to create a depth buffer myself in GLES2? I have not created one cause I thought the default FBO comes with a depth buffer too. On the other hand, why does my opaque front to back stuff work? Shouldn't they be drawn one on top of each other if there was no depth buffer?

Comment: @Tommy I've done some reading and apparently the default frame buffer does not need additional attachments. iOS is an exception where you have to attach your own render and depth buffer but not in C++/Linux. Also I am setting the DEPTH bits correctly in the EGL config so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same old. I found what was wrong. Since I am rendering everything in batches I am not actually using the MVP I calculate for each of the views, but only the MVP of the views that own the batch. So no matter what z value I put here it wasn't going to the shader. I guess I will either have to pass a depth value for each geometry the batch is rendering, or an array of their matrices if possible. Thanks @Tommy for the help anyway.